# Spring: RedisMessageListenerContainer not working when running app from command line via java -jar

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis

I have the following `RedisConfig` in my spring app

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Value("${redis.hostname}")
    private String redisHostName;

    @Value("${redis.port}")
    private String redisPort;

    @Value("${intercom.chats.sync.enable}")
    Boolean enableSync;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisConfig.class.getName());

    @Bean
    public RedisMessageSubscriber redisMessageSubscriber() {
        log.debug("Entered redisMessageSubscriber()");
        return new RedisMessageSubscriber();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter() {
        log.debug("Entered messageListenerAdapter()");
        MessageListenerAdapter listener = new MessageListenerAdapter(redisMessageSubscriber());
        listener.setSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        return listener;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisMessageListenerContainer redisMessageListenerContainer(RedisConnectionFactory redisFactory) {
        log.debug("Entered redisMessageListenerContainer");

        RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(redisFactory);
        if (!enableSync) {
            log.debug("Subscribing to the redis queue {}");
            // Only set the listener if the sync is not enabled
            container.addMessageListener(messageListenerAdapter(),
                    Arrays.asList(new ChannelTopic(Constants.EVENT_MESSAGE_KEY)));
        }
        container.afterPropertiesSet();
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHostName(redisHostName);

        // Checking if redisPort string is an integer or not, this is used in
        // the case of CI environment
        if (redisPort.matches("^-?\\d+$")) {
            factory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(redisPort));
        }
        factory.setUsePool(true);
        return factory;
    }

}
```

The `redisMessageSubscriber()` prints the log and so does `messageListenerAdapter()` but `redisMessageListenerContainer()` doesn't print any which means that it is never entered. The function is not even entered and so none of the 2 logs inside it are displayed.

The result is that it doesn't subscribe to any events. I don't understand why its not working for me. Can someone share their thoughts. Thanks !!

**Edit:** I found that this happens only if I run the project from the terminal using jar -jar command. If I start it from eclipse it works fine :/

Comment: You need to start the container with `RedisMessageListenerContainer.start()` after calling `afterPropertiesSet()`.

Comment: @mp911de Hey I have updated the q u might want to take a look, I'll try this as well though

Comment: Looks like an IDE vs. build problem then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work. I had added the annotation `@EnableRedisHttpSession` on a config class and this was causing the issue. I guess both of them (`@EnableRedisHttpSession` and `RedisMessageListenerContainer`) don't work at the same time, though I would like to get a better answer.  :/